# Problem with discord.py (how can I send an ephemeral message with embed table)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

User press the button and discord bot send him table of roles, but i can use only text with ephemeral message

```
        response = await self.client.wait_for('button_click', check = lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
        if response.component.custom_id == 'bth_roles_info':
            await response.respond(content = 'Action one')
        elif response.component.custom_id == 'bth_booster_perks':
            await response.respond(content = 'Action two')
        elif response.component.custom_id == 'bth_server_rules':
            await response.respond(content = 'Action three')
```

How can I add an embed message to this code?

Comment: This is not `discord.py`, nor is it valid python syntax.

Comment: Why? This is python syntax

Comment: This would result in an `IndentationError: Unexpected Indent`

Comment: And now?))) But how can I sand embed message?

Comment: Can't you just create an embed and then send it with the argument ephemeral=True?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, then you're looking to build an embed and send it ephemerally.
Resource: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#embed

This is how to create an embed:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="This is your Embed Title", 
                      description="This is your description", 
                      color=discord.Colour.random())
```

Then when you want to use your embed later, and send it, you can update your response command to:

```
await response.respond(content = 'Action three', embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
```